# How can I determine multiple clicks without exploiters?

Tags: javascript

So I tried to figure out what is the speed of average click speed of 6 clicks a second to prevent exploiters in my clicker game. I don't really know if this is the best option though.

Here is my Javascript:

```js
setInterval(Click, 1);
function Click() {
  score++;
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = score;
    clearInterval(Click);
  };
}
```

And my HTML:

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="Click()" >
  Cash out your score! 
    </button>
    <hr>
    <p>
      Score: <p id="demo" >0</p> <p style="display: inline;" >   Note: when you start you get one click per second, so you have to rely on that.</p>
    </p>
```

Also, when the click event fires, it only works once.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you are not going to be very successful in identifying this. Since there is hardware involvement here, simulating a click is going to be always faster. And the hardware's speed is limited by our own limitations to become the fastest clicker.

However, I just built on your snippet. Here is what we can find.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var prevDate = Date.now()
var click = function (elem) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });
//   console.log(evt); // This will print the event details. 
  console.log(Date.now() - prevDate)
  prevDate = Date.now()
    // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
for(var i =0; i<10 ; i++) {
  click(btn);
}
```

The maximum I got was 10, in multiple runs. There will be a lot of reasons, browser specific, OS specific for the variations and I don't know them.

If you do anything more than this, it has an overhead and you cannot contribute that to the mouse click. Like just printing the event itself increases the difference by multiple folds.